# Two Nands Make an And

Tags: logical-operators, opcode, instruction-set

I wrote an algorithm for computing the multiplication of two binary numbers. In my instruction set, there is no and instruction, just a nand(not and). I read and it logically makes sense that two nands make an and. I feel this is really simple and I'm overthinking it

So for example, if i wanted to compute the and of 3 & 1, how could i do this using two nand operations with two instructions

My ISA executes a Nand like the following and has 8 registers numbered 0-7. For example:

nand 1 2 3 (nand contents in reg1 and reg2 and store in reg3)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not "[a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)".

Answer (score 3):

```
result = x nand y
result = result nand result
```

Use the second `nand` as a `not`.

Answer (score 2):

NAND is `~(a & b)` so if you give it another `~`, you get an and. If you don't have any NOT gates, you can build one out of NANDs: `~(a & a)` is the same as `~a`. Put it together, and you get

```
nand r1 r2 r3
nand r3 r3 r3
```